Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

<sql:setDataSource var="con" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" user="system" password="manager" />

<sql:update dataSource="${con}" sql="INSERT INTO student VALUES (8, 'ggg', 44)"/> <c:out value="Record inserted successfully." />

I tried to insert one record into student table to my oracle database.
but it showing unable to get connection error. What can be the issue?

The issue can be lots of things.  Please provide the complete error message and stacktrace so that we can help you narrow down the cause.
